# Can't reach the next URL (Scrapy)

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to write a code in Python (3.11.4), using Scrapy (2.9.0) via Visual Studio Code (1.80.1).
I know that it's not the proper way to write it. I have another project and this part is the only part I couldn't get to work. That's why I took it out so I can play with it easily.

```
import scrapy
import scrapy
import w3lib.html


class KmjklolSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "kmjklol"
    allowed_domains = ["ensonhaber.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.ensonhaber.com/gundem/mehmet-ozhaseki-acikladi-haftaya-istanbulda-calismalara-basliyoruz"]

    def parse(self, response):
        sourcecode = response.xpath("//article")
        for myinfo in sourcecode:
            title = w3lib.html.remove_tags(myinfo.xpath(".//div[@class='article-title']/h1").get().strip())
            desc = w3lib.html.remove_tags(myinfo.xpath(".//div[@class='article-title']/h2[@class='desc']/text()").get().strip())
            text = myinfo.xpath(".//div[@class='article-body']/p[@class='text']/text() | //div[@class='article-body']/p[@class='text']//*/text()").getall()
            yield {"Title: ": title, "Description: ": desc, "Content: ": text}

        nextpage = response.xpath("//div[@class='shotnews mb-30']/a/@href").extract()
        print(nextpage)

        completed_nextpage = response.urljoin(nextpage)

        yield scrapy.Request(completed_nextpage)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcDyC.png)

I want my code to reach the news site, take the title, description and the news content, which it does. But the part I got stuck is that I can't reach the next URL that is given to me by the suggested news on the right side. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: all of the suggested articles are rendered dynamically. so you will not be able to parse them with scrapy alone.